# Top menu bar is too narrow

Tags: gnome

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36.3 and my top menu bar became too narrow, resulting in distorted icons. It looks like this [image] How to restore top bar to original height?

Comment: There is currently a bug in Mutter where the font scaling setting is not honored. See duplicate question for a temporary workaround.

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Thanks for the link